# Can Wicket be set to generate low-level logs?

Tags: logging, wicket

Is it possible to see what Wicket is trying to do while rendering a page, in logs? For example, something like:

> ...
>   trying to render component A
>   getting data from model for component A
>   ...

and so on.

Comment: Just use a debugger. Even if possible (and I don't think it is), this level of logging would get really verbose, making it completely useless.

Comment: or profiler if you're trying to figure out memory or performance problems and such

Answer (score 5, accepted):

set the logging level in your log config/properties file for package
`org.apache.wicket to debug or trace`. You will see hundreds of lines of logs.